# Regular Expression should not match null or whitespace

Tags: regex, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I found something that should have answered my question:

[Regular Expression Validation error does not show up on entering a whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462968/regular-expression-validation-error-does-not-show-up-on-entering-a-whitespace?rq=1)

However, the answer did not work for me. I am trying to find non-zero, positive or negative integers. I use:

```
^-?[1-9][0-9]*
```

It works properly, except when empty or with whitespace. I tried:

```
^-?[1-9][0-9]*\ {0,0}$
```

This did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this: ^[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*$
That didn't work. The look ahead (or behind, which I think this is) seems to test that the number 0 is not followed be a digit. That doesn't appear to solve my problem. I wonder, could this be because this is part of an asp.net RegularExpressionValidation control?

Comment: I tried an alternate way. I put two validation server controls on the textbox. RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator, using Display=Dynamic on both. The problem here is that only the first one ever shows. If I put the RequiredField first, it shows it's error message when appropriate. But RegEx never displays. And vice-versa. Now, I'm not sure which way I should go. Is it possible RegularExpressionValidators never test for nulls even if you say, so the RequiredFieldValidator has a purpose? Sounds more philosophical than computer science...

Comment: I tried the most basic regex I could imagine to just check to make sure there's no whitespaces or empty: ^\S+$  That never works. I'm beginning to think RegularExpressionValidator isn't going to let me check for spaces or nulls. It's damn weird.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[+-]?(?!0$)\d+$
```

You can try this.See demo.`?!` is negative lookahead to test if string is not 0.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/18

Comment: @anubhava no it wont.Just didnt read integers and other stuff.this employs negative lookahead where as yours dont.

Answer (score 1):

Use use anchor `$` here:

```
^[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*$
```

That is:

- `^` - Line start
- `[+-]?` - Optional `+` or `-`
- `[1-9]`- Number between 1 to 9
- `[0-9]*` - 0 or more digist
- `$` - End of Input

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it is because the RegressionExpressionValidator is not designed to check for whitespace or blanks, you need a RequiredFieldValidator as well.

[Can't get asp.net regular expression validator to work for blank passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303845/cant-get-asp-net-regular-expression-validator-to-work-for-blank-passwords)

Now I just have to figure out why Display=Dynamic isn't doing the job...